# How to read and overwrite a file in AWS s3 using Lambda and Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying the following. But when i overwite a file which was invoked by lambda, due to this it is going in a loop. Can you anyone please help me. Below also pasted the piece of code which am using for lambda.

Task

1. Read a file in a folder called 'Folder A' when it is uploaded to this folder
2. Then replace a particualr column which has character more then 10
3. then upload this file back to the same folder but unfortunately it is going in a loop due to lambda invoke
4. Tried moved to a different folder called TrimmedFile then it is working fine without any loops.

**Can someone tell me how to read, edit, save the file in the same folder which was invoked?**

```
    import json
    import urllib.parse
    import boto3
    import json
    import os
    import csv
    print('Loading function')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        # Get the object from the event and show its content type
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            #print("CONTENT TYPE: " + key['ContentType'])
            #for record in event['Records']:
            print("file name " + key)
            #bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            #file_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        
        file_key = key
        csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
        csvcontent = csvfile["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
        file = csvcontent.split("\n")
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        line_count = 0
        colindex = ''
        content = []
        contentstring = ''
        s33 = boto3.resource('s3')
        copy_source = {
              'Bucket': bucket,
              'Key': file_key
            }
        new_bucket = s33.Bucket(bucket)
        print(file_key)
        print(bucket)
        src_folder = "FolderA/"
        new_filekey = file_key.replace(src_folder,"")
        print(new_filekey)
        new_bucket.copy(copy_source, 'BKP/' + new_filekey )
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row:
                row = list(map(str.strip, row))
                if line_count == 0:
                    if 'ColToTruncate' in row:
                        colindex = row.index('ColToTruncate')
                        line_count += 1
                    else:
                        print('No ColToTruncate column found in '+ file_key)
                        return 'No ColToTruncate column found in '+ file_key
                else:
                    if len(row[colindex ]) >= 10:
                        row[colindex ] = row[colindex ][0:2]
                    line_count += 1  
                content.append(row)
                contentstring += ', '.join(row) 
                contentstring = contentstring + '\n'
        #print(contentstring)
        #filename = file_key + '.csv'
        uploadByteStream = bytes(contentstring.encode('utf-8'))
        #new_key = 'TrimmedFiles/' + new_filekey
        s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key , Body=uploadByteStream)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have created an event Trigger on S3 and associated it with Lambda and when you are replacing the file you get the lambda triggered and it becomes a loop.

There could be 2 ways to handle it:

1.Configure a PUT OR POST event type ( which ever suits your case) to trigger the lambda. Now save the updated file at another location and then copy it to the original one. Doing this s3 will generate a "S3:ObjectCreated:Copy" event which will not invoke the Lambda again.

```
 # Copying file from secondary location to original location
 copy_sr = {
        "Bucket":bucket,
        "Key"   :file_key_copy
        
    }
    
    s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_sr, 
    final_bucket,file_key_copy
    )
    
    #Deleting the file from the secondary location
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket,
    Key=file_key_copy
    )
```

2.Use SQS queue and configure it not to precess any message received twice in a specified period of time ( depending on the frequency of file getting updated)

Comment: The first option was really cool. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is to demonstrate how to **read** a file and and **replace** it after **editing**. It can act as a skeleton code.

```
import boto3
import base64
import json
import io


client = boto3.client('s3')
res = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    file_key = event['file_key']
    file_obj = s3_res.Object("bucket_name", file_key)

    content_obj = file_obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8') # fetching the data in

    res.Object("bucket_name", file_key).delete() # Here you are deleting the old file

    ######Performing your operation and saving in new_data variable#########

    new_file = io.BytesIO(new_data.encode())

    client.upload_fileobj(new_file, "bucket_name", file_key) # uploading the file at the exact same location.
```

Comment: the last line which says to upload in the same location. Will it not invoke a lamda again and go on a infinite loop.

Comment: @Jeeva In the skeleton code, what I am doing is, that I am receiving input of key from event, then I am using that key to read the file from S3, after reading the file and storing in __content_obj__ , I am deleting the file, after that once a certain operation on __content_obj__ is done and stored in another variable called __new_file__, converting that data to bytes and then uploading it on the exact same location in S3.

Comment: Tried your skeleton code and still it is going in a loop

Comment: @Jeeva It seems the problem is in the updation part Of file.